# the expectation of linear combination of chi-squared random variables with 1 degree of freedom

Tags: chi-squared

I'm calculating the problem descripted in the title, and found it a little bit hard, here is the problem:

Suppose $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is standard normal random variables, now we need to calculate the expectation of linear combination of the square of standard normal variables, that is $$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{L}c_i X^2_i\right].$$

There is a paper [1] giving a more general circumstance but the result is too complicated to calculate expectation. Another paper [2] gives a subtle theorem to derive a very simple result but it is conditional on a complicated condition.

Have you any idea to solve it?

[1]:*Moschopoulos, P. G.; Canada, W. B.*, [**The distribution function of a linear combination of chi-squares**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0898-1221(84)90066-X), Comput. Math. Appl. 10, 383-386 (1984). [ZBL0576.62022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0576.62022).

[2]:*Fleiss, J. L.*, [**On the distribution of a linear combination of independent chi squares**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2284863), J. Am. Stat. Assoc. 66, 142-144 (1971). [ZBL0218.62014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0218.62014).

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^L c_i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{L}c_i X^2_i\right] = \sum_{i=0}^{L}c_i\mathbb{E}\left[ X^2_i\right] = \sum_{i=0}^{L}c_i,$$
where the first equality comes from linearity of expectation and the second from the fact that your random variables are zero mean and variance 1.

Comment: It seems that I've asked a stupid question :-). I forgot the linear properties of taking expectation, complicated the problem. Thank you!